# Find the control for this system of ODE minimizing the energy.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, control-theory, integral-equations, optimal-control

Suppose I have the system of ODE $$x'(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$$
$$x(0)=x_0$$
$t$ is defined on an interval $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ containing $0$, for $x(t)=(x_1(t),...x_n(t))^T$, $x_i : I \to \mathbb{R} $ differentible on $I$, $i=1,2,...,n$, $A$ is a real valued $n \times n$ matrix, $B \in \mathbb{R}^n$ and $u :I \to \mathbb{R}$ is the control.

Find the control $u$ such that $$x(T)=x_T$$ for $T \in I$ and $$\int_0^T u^2(t)dt$$ is minimal.

I am asked to solve this by following the steps below,

Step 1) find the solution of $$x'(t)=Ax(t)+Bu(t)$$

Step 2) define a linear operator $L$ such that $x(T)=x_T$ can be written as $$Lu=x_T$$

Step 3) find minimal quadratic solution for the above equation.

I am asked to first solve $x'=Ax+Bu$, so by using variation of parameters and the exponential matrix, I get the fundamental solution
$$x(t)=e^{At}x_0+\int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}Bu(s)ds$$

Then I must define a linear operator, the operator $$Lu=e^{At}x_0+\int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}Bu(s)ds$$ is not linear but the particular solution $$Lu=\int_0^t e^{A(t-s)}Bu(s)ds$$ is,
so I am guessing that I only need the particular solution (is this right? and if yes why?)

So I get $$x(T)=Lu=\int_0^T e^{A(T-s)}Bu(s)ds=x_T$$

So now I need to find a minimal quadratic solution to this integral equation, I suppose that means I should find a $u$ such that $$\int_0^T u^2(s)ds$$ is minimal, I am not sure on how to approach this, one idea I had is to use Lagrange multipliers, so I define $$h=\int_0^T u^2(s)ds-\int_0^T \lambda (s) e^{A(T-s)} B u(s)ds$$ where $\lambda (s)$ are the Lagrange multipliers, but I am not sure whether this is right.

I am aware of other approaches to such problems like for example, by defining the Hamiltonian $H=u^2+\lambda (Ax+Bu)$ of the problem and solving the equations $$\dot{\lambda }=-H_x$$
$$\dot{x}=H_{\lambda }$$
Such that $$H_u=0$$
but I don't know if this is related to the approach I am asked to take.

Can you help?

Comment: A well written question that shows you put thought into efforts to solve, and formatted correctly.  Upvoted.

Comment: How familiar are you with the controllability Gramian? Namely, there is an elegant solution to this problem using that.